# BlueBird Promises returns "Undefined" when return inside "then" function

Tags: node.js, promise

Here is my Code:

**Checking if user is folowing official Twitter Account (here I've returned new Promise**

```
var isFollowing = function(sender) {
    return new promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var following = false;
        var params = {
            source_id: sender,
            target_screen_name: config.get('twitter.official_account')
        };
        TwitObj.get('friendships/show', params, function(err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                following = data.relationship.source.following;
                resolve(following);
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**Validation:**

```
var validateMsg = function(dm) {
    var sender = getSender(dm);
    var result = [];
    isFollowing(sender.id)
        .then(function(response) {
            if (!response) {
                result = interactiveMessage(false, lang.__('FOLLOW_MAIN', sender.name));
                console.log(result); // Displays as expected
                return result; // Not returning value Do I need to return promise again? If yes, WHY?
            }
        });
};
```

**Main Implementation:**

```
var direct_message = function(msg) {
    verifyAccount().catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
    var dm = msg.direct_message;
    var result = validateMsg(dm);

    console.log(result);
};
```

Questions is how should I force validateMsg function to return `result` variable inside `then` function.

> **Update:** While debugging, I got to know that, `console.log(response)` in
>   validation function is displaying later after throwing undefined in
>   "then" function which means program is not able to get response
>   immediately and due to async nature, I/O is not getting blocked. How
>   to tackle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually returning anything in the validateMsg function. You're returning a synchronous value ( `result` ) in the `.then` function which is a separate function.

The second thing to consider is that you're expecting the validateMsg function, which is asynchronous to behave synchronously.

`var result = validateMsg(dm);`

The way to achieve what I believe you're looking to do involves making the following changes:
1) Return the promise chain in the validateMsg function.

```
    var validateMsg = function(dm) {
    var sender = getSender(dm);
    var result = [];
    return isFollowing(sender.id)
      .then(function(response) {
          if (!response) {
              result = interactiveMessage(false, lang.__('FOLLOW_MAIN', sender.name));
              return result;
          }
        // Not sure what you want to do here if there is a response!
        // At the moment you're not doing anything if the validation
        // is successful!
        return response;
    });
```

};

2) Change your function call, since you're now returning a promise.

```
    validateMsg(dm).then( function( result ){
      console.log( result );
    })
```

3) Consider adding a catch somewhere if only to help you debug :)

```
    validateMsg(dm).then( function( result ){
      console.log( result );
    })
    .catch( function( err ){
      console.log( "Err:::", err );
    });
```

Comment: Looks interesting. I think I've confused you by providing all of my code. Let me revise my question and get back to you :) Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No Need!! Your resolution Worked like charm!! I just returned another promise inside validateMsg function. Thanks for your efforts buddy!!!

Comment: :) I recommend reading a little about some promise patterns. I recommend this article by @nolanlawson https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Comment: Yeah thanks! I'm kinda of new in NodeJS although switching from PHP is an easy task!

Answer (score 0):

The validationMsg function does not have a return value, thus the result in the main function has the value undefined.  Try to put return in front of isFollowing so the function returns a promise, then treat validationMsg as a promise.